# Google Maps will not load KML layer from my site

Tags: google-maps, kml

I have a site that contains kml. The kml is shown as a layer in Google Maps. The maps are on the same site. Until recently (may 12th), this worked fine, but now it stopped working. The kml itself is OK, it can be used in Google Earth. When I copy the kml to another site I can load it in Google Maps without any problem.
Is it possible that my site is on a "blacklist" for some reason? Traffic is low. I did not use an API key. I do now but that did not solve the problem.

You can see the difference here:
1 - [with kml from my site](http://data.3tu.nl/repository/aux:test/TEST1)
2 - [with kml placed elsewhere](http://data.3tu.nl/repository/aux:test/TEST2)
The first one fails, the second one works. The kml placed elsewhere is an exact copy of the kml from my site. The kml from my site is served with media-type application/vnd.google-earth.kml+xml. It is dynamically generated.

Comment: whoever downvoted this question is an idiot. Upvoted for relevant question that I need an answer to as well.

Answer (score 4):

In my case i got FETCH_ERROR on kml status-

[image]

Because my site allow only tls 1.2 secure connection.

When i put the files on another server- it's work.

---

Update 1-

It happend again after sometime, this time use the same domain helped.

---

Update 2-

Now it happened to me because of uppercase letters... If it happens to you -

So - **make sure that the link you put has uppercase and lowercase letters in the KML file just like in the file on the server...**

Answer (score 0):

from the [Google Maps documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/support/kmlmaps)

> From February 2015, maps created in the classic Google Maps — https://maps.google.com/ — will no longer load KML/KMZ files from external websites. However, we know that KML files are a really useful way to work with geographic data, so we’ve added KML to Google My Maps, and continue to support this format with other Google Maps APIs. We hope that one of these options will meet your needs.

Comment: I know. But the change in February was that before, you could load a kml fiel just by passing its url as a query parameter in the Google Maps site. That stopped and instead, you have to use the javascript API to load a kml layer in a Google map on your own site. I made that switch and it worked, until a few days ago. And it still works when I load a copy of the kml file from another site.

Comment: Please add details to your question to clarify that.

Comment: OK, I did. I added my comment as a second paragraph to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Both are valid, the one that doesn't works returns a KmlStatus of **FETCH_ERROR**.  As a guess, I would say that the dynamic generation is taking too long. But there might be some security on your server that is preventing Google's server from fetching it.

from [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#KmlLayerStatus)

> FETCH_ERROR   The document could not be fetched.

1. [from your site](http://feedvalidator.org/check.cgi?url=http%3A%2F%2Fdata.3tu.nl%2Frepository%2Fresource%3Alocation-a0d10f67%2Fgeo%2Fmap)

   - [doesn't work with Google Map KmlLayer](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_GoogleEx_layer-kml_linktoB.html?filename=http://data.3tu.nl/repository/resource:location-a0d10f67/geo/map)
   - Returns KmlStatus: FETCH_ERROR
   - [Works through a proxy](http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/v3_geoxml3_kmltest_linktoB.html?filename=http://www.geocodezip.com/xmlProxy060215.asp?http://data.3tu.nl/repository/resource:location-a0d10f67/geo/map) with the third party parser [geoxml3](https://code.google.com/p/geoxml3/)
2. [placed elsewhere](http://feedvalidator.org/check.cgi?url=http%3A%2F%2Ftudl0867.home.xs4all.nl%2Ftest-big.kml)

   - [works with Google Maps KmlLayer](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_GoogleEx_layer-kml_linktoB.html?filename=http://tudl0867.home.xs4all.nl/test-big.kml)

Comment: Thanks. Now to test whether it is the dynamic generation or a security thing I put a very small static kml file on my server (http://data.3tu.nl/downloads/test/test-small.kml) and that also gives a FETCH_ERROR. So the dynamic generation is not the issue, which leaves us with security on the server. We'll look into that further.

Answer (score 0):

The problem automagically solved itself by waiting a few days. We can only guess what caused it, maybe a temporary glitch on our server which caused Google to stay away for a while and/or sploil it's cache. Anyhow, thanks for the reactions, at least I learned something about testing my kml.