# FETCH_ERROR on parse KMZ in WEB

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have an application that features a dynamic KMZ on a map. This KMZ needs to be updated every 60 seconds, wherefore the URL uses a versioning feature: "?v=201606011903".
Earlier this week the KMZ stopped appearing on the map and the error that the API returns is "FETCH_ERROR".
I'm intrigued as:

- There have been no changes in the application;
- The generation of the KMZ is working properly;
- Tested the KMZ generated in feedvalidator and the result is a valid KML 2.2 feed;

Curiosity:
Apparently there is a delay in the acquisition or parse of the KMZ by the API. If I try to get the same KMZ again after about 3 minutes the API returns the correct results.

Doubt:
There is a maximum time to download or parse of an KMZ by API?

[KMZ analysis on Feedvalidator](http://www.feedvalidator.org/check.cgi?url=http%3A%2F%2Folhovivo.sptrans.com.br%2FFluidezDeOlhoNaVia%2Fbc%3Fv%3D201606011903)

Script for test:

- First change the value of the "v" and run. The error "FETCH_ERROR" will appear.
- Wait about 3 minutes and run the same code (as the same parameter). The KMZ should appear correctly.

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
      #map {
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script>

      function initMap() {
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          zoom: 12,
          center: {lat: -23.5457562, lng: -46.6340402}
        });

        var kmlLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer({
          url: 'http://olhovivo.sptrans.com.br/FluidezDeOlhoNaVia/CB?v=201606011903',
          map: map
        });
        
        kmlLayer.addListener("status_changed", function(a) {
     alert(kmlLayer.getStatus());
        });
      }
    </script>
    <script async defer
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?callback=initMap">
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Does anyone have any idea how I can solve this problem?
Thank's!

Comment: Answerd same question on https://stackoverflow.com/a/57054763/4836581

Answer (score 0):

It can be caused by the [size and complexity restrictions for KML rendering](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/kmllayer?csw=1#restrictions), which is noted that limits are subject to change at any time.

> **Maximum fetched file size (raw KML, raw GeoRSS, or compressed KMZ)**
>
> ```
> 3MB
> ```
>
> **Maximum uncompressed KML file size**
>
> ```
> 10MB
> ```
>
> **Maximum number of network Links**
>
> ```
> 10
> ```
>
> **Maximum number of total document-wide features**
>
> ```
> 1,000
> ```
>
> **Number of KML layers**
>
> There is a limit on the number of KML Layers that can be displayed on a single Google Map. If you exceed this limit, none of your layers will appear on the map. The limit is based on a combination of the number of KMLLayer classes created and the total length of all the URLs used to create those layers.

Aside from the restrictions, common issues which can be encountered in rendering KML/KMZ and tips to resolve these issues can also be found in [KML Best Practice](https://www.google.com.ph/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=6&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjmuc-vq4nNAhWRNpQKHaskBCUQFgg7MAU&url=http%3A%2F%2Fkml4earth.appspot.com%2FkmlBestPractice.html&usg=AFQjCNFIsLzGML3MjNWNhF9n8vs722k-gg&bvm=bv.123664746,bs.2,d.c2I) and [KML Errata](http://kml4earth.appspot.com/kmlErrata.html#validation).

Comment: Sorry. I forgot to tell, but the KMZ size is no larger than 100KB in a single layer and this file do not have NetworkLinks.  
I will read the information that you recommended.  
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try permission on retrieving the file.
I had the same issue

Comment: May be your answer is correct for the given question. But elaborate  more on your answer so other can also understand your answer.