# KML Layer - FETCH_Error

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, kml, kmz

Currently I am facing an issue where I am occasionally getting a FETCH_ERROR when attempting to retrieve the KML Layer. This seems to be based more on the size of the file.

I am serving up a KMZ file, which can vary in size. The size can vary substantially, but the larger the size seems to correlate to the failure. For example the latest FETCH_ERROR was caused by a file with the following attributes (This is not being served up at this URL, the file was placed on this site - zipped format it seems for download).

- [KMZ File](https://filebin.net/md161rewgboiubfu)
- KMZ File Size - **227 KB**
- KML File (doc.kml) - **1.4 MB**

From what I can tell this meets all of Google's requirements.

*Size and complexity restrictions for KML rendering
The Maps JavaScript API has limitations to the size and complexity of loaded KML files. Below is a summary of the current limits.
Note: These limits are subject to change at any time.

- Maximum fetched file size (raw KML, raw GeoRSS, or compressed KMZ)
  3MB
- Maximum uncompressed KML file size
  10MB
- Maximum number of network Links
  10
- Maximum number of total document-wide features
  1,000*

Does anyone know why this KMZ file would return a FETCH_ERROR? I suspect this is related to the size of the file, or perhaps the features aspect.

**Update**

The KMZ File is served up via an IIS Server/Azure VM. The structure of the URL follows - https://example.com/kml/36.866_-88.35410000000002_48280.2_xfggx30w0d3_32e94846-9e11-4448-92bc-50b3cc7bce09_3f580262-55f5-e711-80c3-000d3a1311a6.kmz

While the URL is a bit convoluted, it is being used this way to pass certain data along as the KML layer can be different based on the URL. The map can get a new KML layer every few seconds, and at this point there is no good way to cache a KML layer, so a new URL is retrieved anytime a KML layer changes. I am planning on trying some load testing to see if maybe we can reproduce. Not sure if this information is useful at this point.

Is there a way to get a more meaningful message from the KML Layer status - FETCH_ERROR is not very useful?

Added new [KMZ file](https://filebin.net/ptu58sqbq384mx1n), this was created using SharpKML.

Comment: If you're pointing the API at the "KMZ File" link you provided, that goes to a Filebin web page, and does not directly download the file, which will cause errors.  If you're pointing it at the download link from that page, then it should be able to get the file.  I noticed that it downloads as a .zip instead of .kmz... not sure if that actually makes a difference, but worth trying to fix?  Also, looks like you have just barely under the 1,000 feature limit in the document, so maybe try removing a couple dozen placemarks and seeing if that helps?

Comment: I just placed the file there for ease of download. With that said your comment was helpful with the 1000 feature limit. How did you determine this?

Comment: The 1,000 feature limit is stated in the documentation text that you included in your question.  To count features, I opened your KML in Notepad++ and used the Find/Count tool to quickly count the number of <Document, <Folder, and <Placemark tags. I checked for other feature types (GroundOverlay, Networklink, etc.), but looks like you don't have any of those. I just did it again, and realized I made a mistake before, by counting "Placemark" instead of "<Placemark", so I got 2 hits for each feature.  Looks like you only have 493 Placemarks + 1 Document + 1 Folder, so unlikely to be the issue.

Comment: What kind of a server are you using to serve the file?  Perhaps it has too much latency, is too slow or is on too low bandwidth of a connection.

Comment: While I don't have all of the details, of the servers - it is on an IIS server/Azure VM. I also believe it is a network problem, but I want to ensure that the KML layer looks valid, and that it meets all of google's requirements. I will add a few more details that may possibly shed light on the entire scenario.

Comment: Whatever you are using to compress the kml to kmz isn't doing it correctly.  If I unzip it and zip it back up again (using windows default "sent to compressed..."), [it works](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_GoogleEx_layer-kml_linkToB.html?filename=http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/kmz/SO_20190723b.kmz)  ([original document](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_GoogleEx_layer-kml_linkToB.html?filename=http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/kmz/md161rewgboiubfu.kmz))

Comment: @geocodezip I've added an updated KMZ, this has not been modified in any way and would be served up in this exact format coming from our server. Could you review this for validity, or let me know what tool you are using to validate it?

Answer (score 0):

Answerd same question on https://stackoverflow.com/a/57054763/4836581

In my case it happened because my site allow only tls 1.2 secure connection.

When i put the files on another server- it's work.